# Changing point markers to letters

Tags: arcgis-desktop, symbology

How do I change a symbol to a letter?

I have points on a map denoting 'male' and 'female', and I want the points for the 'male' to be an 'M' and for 'female' to be an 'F'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess there are a couple of ways you can do this. Here is one option.

In the Table of Contents, click the symbol you want to change. When the "Symbol Selector" window pops up, click the "Edit Symbol" button and the "Symbol Property Editor" comes up.

Make sure you are in the "Character Marker" tab. Now, click the drop down menu for font to something like Cambria, for example. You can then click the box for whatever letter you want, change the size, colors, etc.

You can also add and remove your symbol layers in the layers box, as well as add an XY offset if you need. Go back through your menus hitting OK, and your letter will now be your symbol.

Answer (score 2):

You can create your own symbols using ArcGIS. Check out this [A quick tour of symbols and styles](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00s600000003000000) and [About creating new Symbols](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00s600000004000000).

The steps are as follows, open up the symbol selector (right click in the TOC and click properties > symbology)  choose any symbol and click "edit symbol". From the drop down choose > character marker symbol. Choose any font you like, and select the character you need, so in your case 'M' or 'F' you can change the colour and size here as well.

[image]